# Partial Border Color

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I've been trying to play around with the border style properties of view, but was unable to achieve a dynamic partial border colouring of a circle.

This is what I'm trying to do:

[image]
[image]

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: AFAIK You can't do that with css border, you need canvas or SVG.

Comment: https://codeconvey.com/Tutorials/PercentageCircle/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end I implemented [this](https://medium.com/@0saurabhgour/react-native-percentage-based-progress-circle-no-external-library-e25b43e83888) solution for IOS and a variation of [this](https://cmichel.io/react-native-progress-circle) solution for Android (turns out neither solution works for both platforms). If anyone is stuck on this, I recommend using a library that already does it instead of trying to build your own. There are a few though, and I haven't tested how bug-free they are.